# Does docker need Apache to run application

Tags: centos, docker, wordpress

I am installing wordpress  via docker  on centos7 and would likely install other softwares also via docker.do i need Apache to run the Application or docker can run without Apache

Answer (score 0):

I assume by Apache you mean Apaches httpd project.

No, Docker does not need it.

If you run multiple containers and publish them on different ports it is useful to run a reverse proxy in front of it if you don't want to access every application by it's port, but use the default ports for http and https instead. Apache httpd is one product you can use for that, among others.

Comment: Yes i meant Apache httpd

Comment: I have installed wordpress via docker and it returns an error showng showing  bind address in use.I observed nginx and apache  are using my port 80 and 443.pls advice me on what to do

Comment: Use another port and configure nginx or Apache as reverse proxy for it.

Comment: thanks Gerald Schneider